# A Compact Manifold with odd Euler characteristic whose tangent bundle admits a field of lines

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I understand that the top Stiefel Whitney class is an obstruction for the tangent bundle of a manifold to have a trivial line sub-bundle. I am looking for a counterexample when removing the word "trivial", i.e: A compact manifold $M$ of dimention n such that $w_n(TM)\neq0$ (or equivalently $\chi(M)$ is odd) and there exists a sub-bundle $\xi\subset TM$ with $\operatorname{rank}(\xi)=1$.

After some thought I understand why one cannot find an example using surfaces, odd-dimensional manifolds or any of $S^n$,$T^n$,$\mathbb{R}P^n$,$\mathbb{C}P^n$.   I also understand why manifolds with $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$ will not work, and why such a manifold (if it exists) cannot be null-cobordant.

My intuition on 4-manifolds (or god forbid anything higher dimensional) is not good enough to know where to look. Any insight as to where one should look for such a creature (or why the hell it should not exist) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe there is no example satisfying all your constraints.  If I recall (my memory is a little foggy on this) the result likely goes back to Hopf, and one of his variations on the Poincare-Hopf index theorem. This question might be addressed in the Milnor and Stasheff text. Here is one way to argue the point.

Say the tangent bundle of the manifold $N$ admits a field of lines.  Then (at worst) some 2:1 cover of $N$ admits an everywhere non-vanishing vector field.  Since the Euler characteristic is the obstruction to such a vector field existing (Poincare-Hopf index theorem) the Euler characteristic of this covering space is zero.  But $\chi N$ is a multiple of the euler characteristic of the cover.

i.e. your assumption that the Euler characteristic is odd excludes the possibility of a 1-dimensional sub-bundle.

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer! I feel so silly I missed this.

Comment: This is the kind of question you'd hope would be answered in most texts that cover Poincare-Hopf but it seems to get lost too often.

Comment: Definitely! It's quite odd that alot of texts bother proving that if $\chi(M)=0$ then there exists a nonvanishing vector field (which if I recall correctly is abit involved as you need to push all zeros of a vector field to a small ball by a diffeomorphism) but not this simple thing.

Comment: Can your answer be generalized to a noncompact manifold in the following sense: A manifold $M$ (not necessarily compact) which admits a field of lines must have a non-vanishing vector field? Poincare hopf heavily uses compactness but I can't seem to prove or disprove this.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: Any non-compact $M$ will admit both a line field and a non-vanishing vector field (essentially by pushing all thezeros to infinity). By the way, Diarmuid Crowley and I wrote a (semi-)expository article on the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem for line fields, which contains this statement and references to the original literature:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04073

Comment: Could you elaborate on this alittle? I didn't find a proof/reference in your article and tried proving this myself and failed. I understand that you can assume you already have a vector field with a discrete set of zeroes (by generic transversality or something) and that the strategy would probably be to connect them by a curve and "push them all to infinity" by an isotopy or something but I can't seem to understand precisely how to do this.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: That's the idea. I must admit I couldn't immediately find a reference where the details of the argument are written out, but the intuition is clear. If you need a proof for some reason, you could use obstruction theory: the only obstruction to sectioning the sphere tangent bundle of $M^n$ lives in $H^n(M;\pi_{n-1}(S^{n-1}))$, a group which is zero if $M$ is non-compact.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma$ be the canonical (real) line bundle over $RP^2$. In other words, $w_1(\gamma)\neq 0$. The total Stiefel-Whitney class of the Whitney sum $\gamma\oplus\gamma$ is $(1+w_1(\gamma))^2=1+w_1(\gamma)^2$. So $w_2(\gamma\oplus\gamma)=w_1(\gamma)^2$ which is nonzero.

Comment: $\gamma\oplus\gamma$ is not isomorphic to $T\mathbb{R}P^2$ (and neither is $\gamma\oplus1$) as they don't even have the same first Stiefel-Whitney class. In general every real projective space will fail to satisfy my demands as $TS^n$ admits a line sub-bundle only if $n$ is odd, in which case $w_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)=0$ (notice that one can pull back a line sub-bundle of $T\mathbb{R}P^n$ to a line sub-bundle of $TS^n$).

Comment: No surfaces will do either, as the only closed surfaces $M$ which admit a line sub-bundle of $TM$ are the torus and the Klein bottle (because such a surface (if not orientable) would have an orientable 2-cover which admits a nowhere vanishing vector field i.e: is a torus), both of which have $\chi(M)=0$ and hence $w_2(TM)=0$.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you wanted the bundle to be tangent.